# Elements of vector still reference-able after calling clear( )?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

In the following code, I print the first element of a vector and its size, before and after calling clear( ) method of the in-built vector.

However, even after calling clear( ), I can still refer to the element of the vector( although the size is reset to '0').

Is this expected behaviour or have I not understood the behaviour of clear( ) well?

CODE:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

  cout << vec[0] << " " << vec.size() << endl;

  vec.clear();

  for(auto i : vec)
    cout << i << " ";
  cout << endl;

  cout << vec[0] << " " << vec.size() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

1 5

1 0

Comment: It's just undefined behavior to access the 0th element of a vector of size 0.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexing operator of `std::vector<>` *does not* check the index. Since it's Undefined Behavior, you might get "what was there before", or it might crash (or "whatever").

You have the `at` member function, which will throw if index is out of range. That is:

```
cout << vec.at(0) << " " << vec.size() << endl;
```

near the end of your `main()` will throw.

Comment: Yes I tried the at( ) member function and it did throw an exception so looks like using the at( ) member is better to write safe code. Thanks for the clarification.